# Blender Game Engine: RayCast to get a point

Tags: game-engine

I'm making an fps game and I have a gun which I want to have a laser sight (similar to this: https://imageshack.com/f/jxdscn2857sj)

I've tried to do this using the logic editor but I realised I would most likely need to use python. So basically, is there a way - like in Unity - to get a point by raycasting?

Here's an image of what I want: [image]

Comment: Image link doesn't work for me.

Comment: please post the image in your question. External links are not good and can (as in this case) expire.

Comment: @Monster okay I've added the image

Comment: @muhuk okai I've added the image

Answer (score 1):

The [`hitPosition`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bge.types.KX_RaySensor.html#bge.types.KX_RaySensor.hitPosition) of a Ray sensor will give you the coordinate of were a ray hits an object.

To use it, add a *Ray* sensor to the object and connect it to a *Python* controller.

[image: Logic editor]

Create a text block and enter the following script to access the `hitPosition`.

```
import bge

controller = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
owner = controller.owner
ray = owner.sensors["Ray"]

#world coordinates of where ray hit object
ray.hitPosition
```

Finally, enter the script name in the *Python* controller.